# Using subquery inside default constraint

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Below is my test table

```
create table test
(
Id int,
PatientID int,
StudyID int,
PatientCode char(11),
Active bit
)
```

sample data:

[image]

**Expectation:**

I want to create a default constraint for the column 'PatientCode' as below so that for the next new row will have the value automatically.

```
alter table test
add constraint new_PatientCode
default (select top 1 substring(PatientCode,1,3) + '-' + Right('00000'+convert(varchar(5),substring(PatientCode,5,5)+1) ,5) from test
order by id desc)
```

Now when I execute the above alter table statement, I getting the below error statement.

```
Msg 1046, Level 15, State 1, Line 31
Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.
```

**My requirement now is I dont want to use function or insert trigger for this purpose. Do we have any other options?**

Comment: You have a third option:  use an identity column to identify each unique row.  Forget having a "meaningful" patient code.  This is how most databases are organized.

Comment: As already discussed in [this almost identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42508355/column-with-default-function-pass-parameter-or-determine-insert-values/42508857) which was asked one hour ago, no, you cannot do that without a trigger. So what is it? Some kind of homework, or take-away interview?